# Make header responsive for different screen resolutions

Tags: css, wordpress, header, responsive, screen-resolution

I am trying to make header responsive. Currently header is fixed and when  you view it from different screen resoultions it is not lookin good.

```css
#tie-wrapper #theme-header {
    background-image: url(http://example.com/header-image.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I wish to have same image on different resolutions. It should decrease with website. Also logo is centered so the image should be.

I really don't know how to add this image for different resolutions.

Thanks

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Given your code snippet doesn't run, a screenshot or other visual aid showing what it looks like now (and an example of something similar to how you want it to look) would help us answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different images at different screen widths using css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
    #tie-wrapper #theme-header {
        background: url('http://example.com/header-image_FULLWIDTH.jpg') center center/cover no-repeat;
        min-height: 500px;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #tie-wrapper #theme-header {
        background: url('http://example.com/header-image_LARGE.jpg') center center/cover no-repeat;
        min-height: 400px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #tie-wrapper #theme-header {
        background: url('http://example.com/header-image_MEDIUM.jpg') center center/cover no-repeat;
        min-height: 300px;
    }
}
```

I will normally add this code into my template file and using [wp_get_attachement()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/), load up different sizes of images. Or you can hard code it in your styles.css. Either way.

Comment: It is not background image for whole site. It is just for header where this code is located:

#tie-wrapper #theme-header

Comment: fixed withh css selectors.

Comment: can you mark this as the answer if this works for you.

Comment: I had to do it for each screen resolution. It took some time but I did it.

Comment: How many different screen resolutions did you use? I normally just use the above (or numbers close to that) to target Desktop, Tablet, and Mobile.